# Nesting an input inside another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I always thought that `input` elements are prohibited of having DOM contents, as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) (at 'Permitted content') and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) (in 'Tips and Notes').

Now I'm working in a project where several different input element types are rendered and altered in javascript (eg plain `input` text-elements and `select`). In that altering process, a hidden `input` is placed inside those elements, holding the current selected value.

So apparently it is possible via jQuery to add an `input` element into another input element (and using it afterwards):

```js
function doIt() {
  //clear children of parent input
  $('#parentInput').children().remove();

  //create new input and append it to the parent input
  $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'testInput',
    value: 'Test value inserted into nested test input'
  }).appendTo($('#parentInput'));
  
  //get value of new nested input and write it to output div
  $('#output').html($('#testInput').val());
}

$('#doIt').on('click', doIt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Test" id="parentInput">
<button id="doIt">Do it</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

or even a `div`:

```js
function doIt() {
  //clear children of parent input
  $('#parentInput').children().remove();

  //create new input and append it to the parent input
  $('<div id="testDiv">Test value inserted into nested test div</div>').appendTo($('#parentInput'));
  
  //get value of new nested input and write it to output div
  $('#output').html($('#testDiv').html());
}

$('#doIt').on('click', doIt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Test" id="parentInput">
<button id="doIt">Do it</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

My question now is: Why is that possbile via jQuery (and thus via plain javascript, as jQuery is 'just' a wrapper), when `input` elements are not supposed to have DOM content?

Comment: There are several types of input https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp, in some of them we don't put content, in others we do put content. Check the list in the link.

Comment: I'm not sure this is 100% related to your question, but take a look at [Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom).

Comment: browsers support a lot of behavior that is not specifically said to be supported in the W3C/HTML specification. generally you want to steer clear of these "features" as they may not work the same across different browsers, or, even worse, a browser patch could change or break their behavior entirely.

Comment: @MedAli those are still `input` elements which normally can not have other DOM content.

Comment: @JeffNoel thats quite an interesting link, but they are stating themselves that `<input>` cannot host shadow dom

Comment: @jbabey so it is better to stay clear of such "features" to be safe cross-browser and future wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I always thought that input elements are prohibited of having DOM contents, as stated here (at 'Permitted content') and here (in 'Tips and Notes').

You confuse HTML and DOM. HTML is just text. DOM is what the browser creates from that text.

The following is HTML. It's invalid and no browser will create nested nodes from it:

```
<input type="text" value="Test" id="parentInput">
  <div id="testDiv">Test value inserted into nested test div</div>
</input>
```

The DOM tree that the browser creates will most likely look like it came from this HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="Test" id="parentInput">
<div id="testDiv">Test value inserted into nested test div</div>
```

The end tag is ignored. Browsers are forgiving when it comes to parsing HTML.

If you directly manipulate the DOM as you did, then there is no reason for the browser to prevent that. When it's time to render the DOM, the browser knows how to render an input. It doesn't really care if the input node has a child node. It's simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers may (or may not) support behavior that is not specifically supported in the W3C/HTML specification. Generally you want to steer clear of these "features" as they may not work the same across different browsers, or, even worse, a browser patch could change or break their behavior entirely as they are undocumented.